# How can I select multiple edge loops?

Tags: edges, selection-tools

I know that I can select an edge loop in edit mode by pressing Alt and clicking on an edge.

But if I try to select multiple edge loops by holding down shift while selecting a second one, it does not work.

Why and what is the proper way to select multiple edge loops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After selecting the first *edge loop* with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, just go on with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>.

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html):

> Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting an edge selects a loop of edges that are connected in a line end-to-end, passing through the edge under the mouse pointer. Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking adds to the current selection.

In versions pre 2.8 use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select an entire *egde loop*.

Comment: That's weird I had to restart my computer to get it to working. I don't know why.